# Passing Static Values on a COUNT Query (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a series of queries for various sections and websites (e.g. MySite/World, MySite2/World, MySite3/People). It's actually two series of queries - COUNT queries that display pages and more complex queries that retrieve information from my database.

I'm now merging these projects into a single mini encyclopedia on a new website. The query below is from a different, but related, project, but it illustrates what I'm trying to do. Notice that I gave data from each table its own identity with 'GW' AS Site, 'GZ' AS Site, etc.

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 'GW' AS Site, CGW.N, CGW.URL, CGW.Date, CGW.Year, CGW.Brief
FROM calendar_gw CGW
WHERE CGW.URL = :MyURL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'GZ' AS Site, CGZ.N, CGZ.URL, CGZ.Date, CGZ.Year, CGZ.Brief
FROM calendar_gz CGZ
WHERE CGZ.URL = :MyURL
ORDER BY Year");
$stm->execute(array(
'MyURL'=>$MyURL
));
```

Now I'd like to know if there's a way to similarly give an ID to multiple tables in a COUNT query, like this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(num) as num FROM (
SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM pox_topics WHERE URL = :MyURL
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :MyURL
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(Taxon) AS num FROM gz_life WHERE Taxon = :MyURL
) AS X";
```

I actually want to give each subquery TWO ID's - website and section. For example, the values for the middle query should be $Site = 'PX', $Section = 'People'.

I've tried the obvious solutions, like...

```
SELECT 'PX' AS Site COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people WHERE URL = :MyURL

SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num 'PX' AS Site FROM people WHERE URL = :MyURL

SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM 'PX' AS Site people WHERE URL = :MyURL
```

But nothing works so far. My ultimate goal would probably look something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people ('PX' AS Site 'People' AS Section) WHERE URL = :MyURL
```

Can someone either show me the proper syntax or tell me if it's impossible to pass static values on a COUNT query? If what I'm trying to do is impossible, then I assume the only solution is to create a second, intermediate subquery designed only to pass static values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version is fine, almost.  It just needs a comma:

```
SELECT 'PX' AS Site, COUNT(URL) AS num
FROM people
WHERE URL = :MyURL;
```

Comment: Stupid me - I actually tried that once and got an error message. But I took your advice and tried it again, this time making sure I added the same thing to EACH subquery and it works.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom . . . Sometimes it helps to have another set of eyes look things over.

Comment: Yes. ;) One more question, though I'm not getting any error messages, I can't echo the static ID I created. I changed it to MySite2 and have tried different variations, including SELECT 'PX' AS '$MySite2' But when put echo $MySite under the query, it doesn't echo any value at all. I probably need to echo it on the display page to get the correct value, but shouldn't it at least display the first value?

Comment: I think your original tip is right, but I'm just not getting how to transform the static ID (e.g. PX) into a variable that I can display or manipulate.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom . . . Please edit your question with the query you are trying.

Comment: Now I get it...In my more advanced query, I turned Site into a variable ($Site) inside a while loop...

    while ($row = $stm->fetch())
   {
    $Site = $row['Site];

So I guess I have to create a while loop for my COUNT query, too. I'll play with that.